# None option in ViewEncapsulation is not working

Tags: angular

I am using View Encapsulation with NONE But at the time of ruuing the code it is not working. Here is my code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-encap-none',
  templateUrl: './encap-none.component.html',
  styles: [
    `
    h2{
      background: red;
      color:#fff;
    }
  `
  ]
  ,  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class EncapNONEComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

The HTML FILE CODE

```
<h2>Check NONE IS WORKING OR NOT</h2>
```

And when I run the application the out put is in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jezU5.png)

Comment: h2 styles do work:  background is red and color is white for the element. What did you expect the Encapsulation.None would do?

Comment: `ViewEncapsulation.None` makes that the .css in your component is applied to **all** the angulr aplication: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: @Eliseo ok thank u I am just learning